# is inaccessible due to its protection level asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

```cs
public class PropertiesController : Controller
{

    private readonly IPropertyService _PropertyService;
    public PropertiesController(IPropertyService PropertyService)
    {
        _PropertyService = PropertyService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(PropertyModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            await _PropertyService.AddProperty(model);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(index));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(index));
        }
    }
}
```

The [HTTP] post action (AddProperty(model)) is throwing an error with the message (is inaccessible due to its protection level ) despite the fact that the method signature is public. I'm pretty new to this and might not be able to ask my question properly but I hope someone here will understand my challenge and proffer a solution

---

The interfaces are:

```cs
public class PropertyService : IPropertyService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public PropertyService(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task AddProperty(PropertyModel model)
    {
        var property = new PropertyModel
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Title = model.Title,
            ImageUrl = model.ImageUrl,
            Price = model.Price,
            Description = model.Description,
            NumberOfRooms = model.NumberOfRooms,
            NumberOfBaths  = model.NumberOfBaths,
            NumberOfToilets = model.NumberOfToilets,
            Address = model.Address,
            ContactPhoneNumber = model.ContactPhoneNumber
        };
        await _dbContext.AddAsync(property);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

namespace EstateApp.web.Interfaces
{
    public class IPropertyService
    {
        Task AddProperty(PropertyModel model);
    }
}
```

Comment: well... what is `IPropertyService`? can we see that? assuming that you're using Visual Studio: if you put the text cursor into `AddProperty`, then press F12 or right-click and "Go To Definition": where does it take you?

Comment: re now-deleted comment: Can I assume that this is an external package reference, then? (that looks like auto-generated type metadata, since it isn't valid C#); I agree that this looks very unexpected, but my guess would be a dll mismatch between the build and deploy - that's hard for us to look at from here, sadly (not that it matters, but a `class` called `IPropertyService` is very unusual)

Comment: Is `PropertyModel` a public class/record?

Comment: I'm new to c# and was building alongside a tutorial before I stumbled on this issue. presently, I really don't understand the issues

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren the PropertyModel is a public class

Comment: that C# won't compile; is `public class IPropertyService` meant to be an `interface`? or perhaps an `abstract class`? (I'm guessing the first, because the second would still need an extra `abstract` and `override` keyword). If the code won't compile, *all bets are off* - and you're quite likely getting into problems where some old version of the dll is still being looked at (since it can't generate a new one until the code compiles)

Comment: @MarcGravell the public class IPropertyService is meant to be an interface

Comment: and if you *make* it an `interface`, does it start working? (I can only work from the code in the question...)

Answer (score 0):

Add `public` before `class PropertyModel{}` =`public class PropertyModel{}`

*Default access modifier of class is Internal and private for class member.*

and also properties should `public` if you want to change the value of its.